# UPS turns itself on

Tags: power-supply, power-management

So, I shut down my computer, turned off UPS and turned the extension cord (UPS is connected there) off. After an hour, UPS turned on and started beeping. It has happened to me two times before, but still haven't managed to get to the root of the problem. UPS is roughly 2 months old.

Comment: What is the exact make and model of PC and UPS you are using. If it’s coming back on it is most likely some setting in the UPS firmware itself. But I can 100% assure you that what you are doing — connecting the UPS to a switched extension cord and powering it all off — will wear down that UPS pretty quickly. They are designed to be on  24/7. They have built in circuitry to ensure overcharging doesn’t happen. Even if it is 2 months old you are definitely wearing that UPS down each time you power it off. No doubt. If I were you I would just connect it to the wall, leave it on and don’t touch it.

Comment: The computer is self built Ryzen 5 3600, 32 GB RAM, 500GB SSD, 2 TB HDD, RTX 2060Super Graphics, 550W Power supply. UPS is Gembird EnerGenie EG-UPS-034 (900W, 1500VA). I have also two monitors connected to UPS (both are quote new LEDs (22" and 19"). I have had UPSes before, I updated the UPS cause of the computer update. I had old UPS which lasted over 15 years (only had to change the battery once) and I did exactly the same with my old one (turned off every time).

Comment: You wrote "They are designed to be on 24/7"   That is true (and I leave mine on 24x7), but it still should stay off when turned off.